# How do i properly call this function in python?

Tags: python, function

I'm a beginner in python and having some difficulties on how to call a function for a rock, paper and scissor game. The code is as below:

```
def game:
    your = input("Rock, Paper or Scissor? ")
    your.lower()
    list = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]
    import random
    a = random.randint(0, 2)
    weapon = list[a]
    if your == weapon:
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so it's a draw.")
    elif your == "rock" and weapon == "paper":
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so I won.")
    elif your == "paper" and weapon == "scissor":
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so I won.")
    elif your == "scissor" and weapon == "rock":
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so I won.")
    else:
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so you won.")
choice = input("Would you like to play again?(y/n) ")
if choice == "y":
    game()
else:
    print("Thank you for playing.")
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `def game():` ? Otherwise, what's your trouble calling the function?

Comment: BTW, when you call `your.lower()` you **return** a string with all characters lowercased. The string `your` won't change.

Comment: What do you mean, "have some difficulties"? The first thing you need to tell other people is what went wrong, and what was supposed to happen instead.

Comment: Save this code to a file, say x.py, then in the command line, type python x.py

Answer (score 3):

You need brackets, like this:

```
def game():
```

to define a function. And .lower() only *returns* the string in lower case, it doesn't override.

```
your = input("Rock, Paper or Scissor? ").lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how function calls work in Python:

```
#Defining the function
def myFunction():
   print("Hello world")

#Calling the function. Yes, it is this simple.
myFunction()
```

For creating functions with parameters

```
def myFuncWithParams(Word):
   print("Hello" + Word)
myFuncWithParams("World")
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World
```

**In your case:**

```
def game():
    your = input("Rock, Paper or Scissor? ")
    your.lower()
    list = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]
    import random
    a = random.randint(0, 2)
    weapon = list[a]
    if your == weapon:
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so it's a draw.")
    elif your == "rock" and weapon == "paper":
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so I won.")
    elif your == "paper" and weapon == "scissor":
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so I won.")
    elif your == "scissor" and weapon == "rock":
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so I won.")
    else:
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so you won.")
    choice = input("Would you like to play again?(y/n) ")
    if choice == "y":
        game()
    else:
        print("Thank you for playing.")

#Calling the method and staring the game    
game()
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, If this helped you, could you please mark this as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do to call a function is type its name and include arguments if required.

In your case, what you have to do is

```
def game:
    your = input("Rock, Paper or Scissor? ")
    your.lower()
    list = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]
    import random
    a = random.randint(0, 2)
    weapon = list[a]
    if your == weapon:
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so it's a draw.")
    elif your == "rock" and weapon == "paper":
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so I won.")
    elif your == "paper" and weapon == "scissor":
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so I won.")
    elif your == "scissor" and weapon == "rock":
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so I won.")
    else:
        print("You chose " + your + " and I chose " + weapon + " so you won.")
choice = input("Would you like to play again?(y/n) ")
if choice == "y":
    game()
else:
    print("Thank you for playing.")


# this is how you call the function
game()
```

Comment: This code is still wrong.